# How to save users last mouse position on a html5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I followed the tutorial from phpacademy on youtube on how to make a HTML5 drawing app.

I'm now done with this tutorial and is trying to make it have more features.
I'm trying to add a text tool at this moment, I know how to draw text onto the canvas and how to change font and textcolor.

What I need help with, is on how to save the users last clicked mouse position on the canvas using javascript.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Html5 Drawing App!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body style='margin: 0'>
    <div id="toolbar">
        <div id="rad">
            Radius <span id="radval">10</span>
            <div id="decRad" class="radcontrol">-</div>
            <div id="incRad" class="radcontrol">+</div>
        </div>
        <div id="colors">
        </div>
        <div id="save">
            <iframe id="downloadframe" hidden=yes></iframe>
            Save
        </div>
        <div id="clear">
            Clear
        </div>
        <div id="text">
            Text
        </div>
    </div>
    <canvas id="canvas" style="display: block;">
        Sorry, Your Browser Is Unsupported. Switch To Another Browser
    </canvas>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <script src="radius.js"></script>
    <script src="colors.js"></script>
    <script src="save.js"></script>
    <script src="text.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Current JS:

```
var pos = new array(0,0);

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var textButton = document.getElementById('text');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.font = "bold 16px Arial";
```

If you need any more details, just tell me.

Comment: Please add the relevant code here.

Comment: Added the current code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to listen for mouseclicks and get the X/Y position: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/56HXT/

You can listen for mouse clicks on the canvas like this:

```
    // listen for mouse clicks on the canvas
    // and give the event to the handlClick function

    canvas.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);
```

When clicked, the handleClick function:

- Receives the click-event argument "e" which contains the X/Y position
- Converts the raw X/Y position to canvas coordinates.
- Reports the X/Y position using the #results paragraph element

Here's the handleClick code:

```
    function handleClick(e){

      // get the mouse position
      // the offset adjustments are needed for the canvas position on the page

      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-canvas.offsetLeft);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-canvas.offsetTop);

      // just testing...report the results

      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML="You clicked at: "+mouseX+"/"+mouseY;
    }
```

Comment: I'll modify this to my needs and then use it. You jsfiddle worked great by the way.